How can I make this OnEdit script run quickly to edit multiple rows in a short span of time?
I have this code to protect rows of my sheet based on a tickmark in Col21.
But the code takes 1 to 3 seconds to execute, so when I check multiple boxes in succession, it skips executing some rows protect script.
How can I make the OnEdit work so that I can protect multiple in quick succession?
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "請求管理"; // Please set sheet name.
  const checkbox = 21; // In this sample, the checkboxes are put in the column "B".

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || range.columnStart != checkbox)
    return;
  const p = sheet
    .getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE)
    .find((r) => {
      const temp = r.getRange();
      return (
        temp.getRow() == range.rowStart &&
        temp.getColumn() == range.columnStart &&
        temp.getNumColumns() == 21
      );
    });
  if (!p && range.isChecked()) {
    const p = range.offset(0, 0, 1, 21).protect().setWarningOnly(true).setDescription(rownum);
  } else if (p && !range.isChecked()) {
    p.remove();
  }
}


Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful to provide an example of input data and expected output.

My experience with onEdit functions is that you have to be patient and will to wait for it to complete.  If your uses just keep on typing then it won't work.  Try using a dialog to make the changes.

@leylou This is the sheet I'm working on.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L_kEyYJwSeLKFS7ppFbxe1-lI7bKu9LKV-0w6NIC1v8/edit?usp=sharing

@Cooper How would I modify the code to work with a dialog?
